# CSS Grid layout for a form

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid, react-flexbox-grid

I have a div named main-filter and within the div, I have two div. Now, I want to create a form with button, labels and input and I want to put two div inside the form and it should look like the below down screenshot. I have the HTML and CSS code but it is not working and couldn't figure out how to do it with CSS grid. I need to make it responsive as well!. I am totally new at CSS grid and any help would much be appreciated. Thank you.

```css
.main-filter {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  color: #287993;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.main-header__left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.3em 0.6em;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.main-header__right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.3em 0.6em;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}

.filter-button1 {
  background: #38acd2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 380px;
  min-width: 370px;
  min-height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input,
button {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #38acd2;
}
```

```html
<div className="main-filter">

  <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
    <div className="main-header__left">
      <label className="start-timestamp">Start Timestamp: </label>

      <input type="text" ref={(input4)=> this.input4 = input4} className="input-item" id="addInput3" placeholder="Ex. 2019-1-12" />
      <label className="source-ip-address">Source IP Address: </label>
      <input type="text" name="source" ref={(input1)=> this.input1 = input1} className="input-item" id="addInput3" placeholder="127.0.0.1 " />

      <label className="service">Service Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="service" ref={(input3)=> this.input3 = input3} className="input-item" id="addInput3" placeholder="Ex. Facebook or Whatsapp *" required />


    </div>


    <div className="main-header__right">
      <label className="end-timestamp">End Timestamp: </label>
      <input type="text" ref={(input5)=> this.input5 = input5} className="input-item" id="addInput3" placeholder="Ex. 2019-1-12" />

      <label className="destinatin-ip-ddress">Destination IP Address: 
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="destination" ref={(input2)=> this.input2 = input2} className="input-item" id="addInput3" placeholder="127.0.0.1 " />


      <button type="submit" className="filter-button1">Apply 
      Filters</button>


    </div>


  </form>



</div>
```

css grid form Image screenshot,
[image: the img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code, I have modified HTML and CSS code, I hope this might help you to achieve expected result.

```css
.main-filter {
  /* margin: 0px; */
  /* padding: 20px; */
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  color: #287993;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.main-header__left>div,
.main-header__right>div {
  display: flex;
}

.main-header__left>div>label,
.main-header__right>div>label {
  width: 40%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* .main-header__left {
    grid-area: 2 / span 1;
    grid-gap: 0;
  } */
  .main-header__right {
    grid-area: 2 / span 1;
    grid-gap: 0;
  }
}

.filter-button1 {
  background: #38acd2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  min-height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #38acd2;
}
```

```html
<div className="main-filter">

  <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
    <div class="main-header__left">
      <div>
        <label class="start-timestamp">Start Timestamp: </label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="source-ip-address">Source IP Address: </label>
        <input type="text" name="source" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="service">Service Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="service" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-header__right">
      <div>
        <label className="end-timestamp">End Timestamp: </label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="destinatin-ip-ddress">Destination IP Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="destination" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label></label>
        <button type="submit" class="filter-button1">Apply Filters</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```